# How to handle multiple async functions in a Lambda handler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-lambda

I have the following code:

```rust
async fn function_handler(_event: Request) -> Result<Response<Body>, Error> {

    let db_eid_cache = create_db_eid_cache();
    let table_eid_cache = create_table_eid_cache();

    try_join!(db_eid_cache, table_eid_cache);

    Ok(Response::builder()
        .status(200)
        .header("content-type", "application/json")
        .body("ok".into())
        .map_err(Box::new)?)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_max_level(tracing::Level::INFO)
        .with_target(false)
        .without_time()
        .init();

    run(service_fn(function_handler)).await
}
```

This does not compile:

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely
the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `(dyn StdError + 'static)`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
join_mod.rs(105, 13): future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
join_mod.rs(107, 13): the value is later dropped here
lib.rs(185, 16): required by a bound in `lambda_http::run`
```

I was trying to add Send for the function_handler() return type but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding + Send + Sync to **all** functions that are called by either of the functions that I am joining fixes the problem.

```
Result<String, Box<dyn error::Error + Send + Sync>>
```